# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application with Entity Framework 6 code first using windows server

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am new to publish and use Windows Server. Can anyone tell me and give me tips that I need to deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application with Entity Framework 6 code first using Windows Server ?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official [ASP.Net MVC website](https://www.asp.net/mvc), and two links for a quick start : [Quick start with ASP.Net MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/) and [Quick start with ASP.Net MVC 5 and EF 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/)

In the second tutorial, you will find tips to deploy your solution to Azure. For more option for the deployment, you can see the [deployement section](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment) on the offical documentation or on [MSDN Web Deployment overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx) to deploy your solution on premise.